# Nested Classes with Typescript and ServiceStack

Tags: typescript, servicestack

We are using [typescript-ref](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#simple-command-line-utilities-for-typescript) to generate the dtos.ts file. The issue is that the response classes contains nested classes with the same name. When generating the typescript classes, the nested classes ends up in the global scope, causing duplicate identifier error

Any idea if this can be configured with typescript-ref, so that these nested classes does not end up in the global scope.

**C#**

```
public class FirstResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public Person Teacher { get; set; } = new Person();

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

public class SecondResponse
{
  public string Result { get; set; }
  public Person Teacher { get; set; } = new Person();

  public class Person
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Typescript**

```
...

export class Person
{
    public Name: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}

export class Person
{
    public Id: number;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}

export class FirstResponse
{
    public Result: string;
    public Student: Person;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<FirstResponse>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}

export class SecondResponse
{
    public Result: string;
    public Teacher: Person;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<SecondResponse>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use nested classes if you would like your Services to be interoperable, they're a C# feature that's not recommended for DTOs that you'd like to make available in different languages.

In most [Add ServiceStack Reference supported languages](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) they're generated as first class DTOs in the same namespace as other DTOs.

Comment: @Kai-Rune that's irrelevant, they're not analogous to C# nested classes and not used. DTOs are top-level message schemas used to describe your service contract which should be unique across your entire service boundary if you want them to be interoperable.

Answer (score 0):

Using namespace would have solved it, since typescript merges classes and namespaces, ref 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes

```
export class FirstResponse
{
    Result: string;
    Teacher: FirstResponse.Person;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<FirstResponse>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}

export namespace FirstResponse {
    export class Person {
        Name: string;

        public constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
    }
}

export class SecondResponse {
    Result: string;
    Teacher: SecondResponse.Person;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<SecondResponse>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}

export namespace SecondResponse {
    export class Person {
        Id: number;

        public constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
    }
}
```